# GWT Deployment to JBoss

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jboss, jetty, redirect

I am currently working on a project which has a GWT frontend and a seperate Java module with servlets and a REST interface on the backend.  The project when deployed runs on a single JBoss server.

I am running into difficulties though as when I run the GWT app in hosted mode (in eclipse) the jetty server does not have a deployed Java module to interact with.

My idea was to setup a JBoss server which eclipse could deploy into for development purposes, the problem with this is that the installer for the product sets up a JBoss server with a GWT app already embedded in it, so redeploying into this JBoss instance might cause problems?

My other idea would be to create a second JBoss server to host the GWT app, with some sort of url redirect for the rest calls which would redirect to the first JBoss instance.  Is this possible?

EDIT: Can I do this with the built in jetty server in eclipse and not have to worry about using a seperate JBoss server.  In other words can I somehow get the jetty server in eclipse to redirect particular requests to a different URL?

Comment: the Jetty tag is for standalone Jetty or general Jetty questions. GWT hosted mode is neither.  GWT hosted mode is a highly customized embedded Jetty 6.

Comment: It's still Jetty, and the tag says nothing about it being specific to the standalone version.

Comment: I agree with Joakim in that I do not see a Jetty question here, if you have one please make it clearer?

Comment: Just because you happen to be using eclipse + jetty doesn't mean the question is about or related to jetty.  Your question is about jboss deployment options for gwt based apps while inside of eclipse.

Comment: No my question is about jetty too, I have edited to make it clearer, tbh I assumed it was pretty obvious I was asking for options, and the fact I was already using the built in jetty server I thought made it obvious I would be open to solutions which included using the jetty server.

Comment: GWT Hosted mode happens to use Jetty 6, sure, but its incredibly locked down and highly tweaked by Google.  There is really no way for you to control it.  BUT, you can deploy GWT apps to a standalone Jetty  or even an embedded Jetty instance.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: In a deployed environment the GWT app and the Java app are in the same JBoss server, when developing the GWT app however I want to be able to run against the Java app.  Unfortunately due to the way the GWT app is coded before I joined the project the two apps have to be hosted on the same server as the base url is hardcoded.  Can I deploy to something or somehow modify the google tweaked jetty server to make it redirect certain requests to a seperate JBoss instance running the other app?